# Using simple-git, can only get one commit to work

Tags: javascript, git

I'm writing a program that looks for specific "git commit" tags and does a commit when it finds one. I'm using simple-git and JavaScript and I've only been able to get the first commit through using the following

```
const simpleGit = require('simple-git');
const git = simpleGit();
git.init()
  .add(file)
  .commit(message)
```

I've tried not having the .add the second time through and just using git.commit(message) but nothing I've tried has worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean, when you say you're looking for specific "git commit" tags? How are you looking for that?

Comment: Does that thing have any way of showing you what the commands it's issuing are saying?